# How to get the name of the stage in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function(without APIGateWay. I want same lambda function in both test and prod stage and for that I want to get the stage name during runtime. My code is written in java and I know that we can find out the default AWS region using following:

```
Regions regions = Regions.fromName(System.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"));
```

So here are my questions:

1- How to get the name of the stage in which my lambda function is running?

2- What does this default region means? will it be always same as the region in which my lambda function is running?

Any lead is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using this with ApiGateway

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

Comment: I got a solution using environment variables. we can set environment variables using AWS console and can use them in our lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the name of the stage in which my lambda function is
>   running?

For Lambda Proxy integration, you can get the stage name from the `requestContext` in the input stream, which contains the API request serialized as a JSON string by API Gateway. The input data can also include the request's stage variables `stageVariables` (if you use/need any). For example:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
  ...
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  String stage = null;

  JSONObject event = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
  if (event.get("requestContext") != null) {
    JSONObject requestContext = (JSONObject)parser.parse((String)event.get("requestContext"));
    if (requestContext.get("stage") != null) {
      stage = (String)requestContext.get("stage");
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

See [full example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-java).

> What does this default region means? will it be always same as the
>   region in which my lambda function is running?

**YES** according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables) and **NO** according to the [SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java).

The SDK does not reference it. It uses `AWS_REGION` only. See [SDKGlobalConfiguration.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/e377144ed99b69515c6b481802b2c1e03b2575a5/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/SDKGlobalConfiguration.java).